# What is the flowchart corresponding to the "add-sub" program emu8086?

Tags: loops, assembly, emu8086, flowchart

[image: the flowchart]

```
name "add-sub"
org 100h

        mov al, 5 ; bin=00000101b
        mov bl, 10 ; hex=0ah or bin=00001010b
        add bl, al
        sub bl, 1
        mov cx, 8
 print: mov ah, 2 ; print function.
        mov dl, '0'
        test bl, 10000000b ; test first bit.
        jz zero
        mov dl, '1'
  zero: int 21h
        shl bl, 1
        loop print
        mov dl, 'b'
        int 21h
        mov ah, 0
        int 16h
        ret
```

Comment: Please clearly state what you are expecting from the code, the issue you are facing and what efforts you put to resolve your issue.

Comment: This just loops over the bits of an integer and prints it as ASCII 0 or 1.  The first part before the loop adds some constants to create an input for that print loop.